# operation name appended to Backend service UrL in azure API management

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have a logic app with http trigger. I am trying to create a proxy for the logic app using APi management. The issue I am facing is that APi management when calling the Logic App, adds operation name which makes the logic app url invalid.
Example: logic app url: azure/invoke
API manager operation name: pass

Looking at trace logs, URL to call Logic app is:
azure/invoke/pass

I am trying to manually add url to backend service with Blank API design instead of using LogicApp.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details of your api management ? Such as screenshots or something else. As far as I know, it will not result in the logic app url invalid.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It only adds if I do not select Logic App type proxy, instead I try to use the app URL. using '\', does the trick but then the operation name is not given.

Answer (score 2):

API management preserves operation URL template while forwarding request to backend API. You can use rewrite-uri policy to control that behavior. In your scenario try adding `<rewrite-uri template="/"/>`

Comment: Thanks I will try and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Anyone struggling why this is happening.  The url in the front end is being passed in to the back end. You can either make it empty, add a policy to trim that off

[image]